# Fast conversion from String array to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a string array where each element of this array is a csv file's row(comma separated). I want to convert this into a  pandas Dataframe.However when I  tried row by row it is very slow.Can a faster alternative be proposed apart from writelines() followed by pandas.read_csv()?

Comment: post example code and data

Comment: `pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')`. No need to put the contents of the csv file in a list (not array) and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `CSV` Import

In pandas you can read an entire `csv` at once without looping over the lines.

Use [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) with filename as argument:

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

# Set up fake csv data as test for example only
fake_csv = '''
Col_0,Col_1,Col_2,Col_3
0,0.5,A,123
1,0.2,J,234
2,1.4,F,345
3,0.7,E,456
4,0.4,G,576
5,0.8,T,678
6,1.6,A,789
'''

# Read in whole csv to DataFrame at once
# StringIO is for example only
# Normally you would load your file with
# df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/file.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv))

print 'DataFrame from CSV:'
print df
```

---

```
DataFrame from CSV:
   Col_0  Col_1 Col_2  Col_3
0      0    0.5     A    123
1      1    0.2     J    234
2      2    1.4     F    345
3      3    0.7     E    456
4      4    0.4     G    576
5      5    0.8     T    678
6      6    1.6     A    789
```

Comment: Thankyou ! U saved the day

Comment: @SiddharthMuthukumar 
Glad I could help! [Remember to accept, you get +2 reputation!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/292533)